# Is there any page with complete *.pro file syntax?

Tags: qt, syntax, project

I've googled for a while for this and failed to find something that in my opinion should be the first google result... Does anyone know of a page or other resourse with complete (and I mean it) syntax of the Qt project (*.pro) file? All I can find now is random examples on multiples pages, nothing solid.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html

Comment: More specifically, all the syntax is listed on a subpage: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html

Comment: None of these specify **all** legal commands which is what I need. But this didn't stop someone from minusing me...

Comment: Commands are not syntax, and any command you have found that is *not* listed in the docs has no guarantee of being API stable and therefore should be not used in client code.  https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*.pro files are actually qmake project files. There are a lot of information about qmake:

- [qmake Advanced Usage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html)
- [qmake reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-reference.html)
- [Variable reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html)
- [Function reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html)

Comment: As previously - this doesn't specify **all** legal commands (`build_pass` for instance).

Comment: `build_pass` is not a command, it's a variable. I've added more links to my answer.