# .pro extension in C++ project

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a C++ project that contains .pro file. I can not compile it with visual studio 2010 and 2012. can you help me to select the IDE and compiler that can compile the project?

i have seen uint type in the project. uint or unsigned int?
cheers
Ehsan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762199/is-there-any-page-with-complete-pro-file-syntax

Comment: Where did you get it from? Isn't there any more information available (README.txt, etc.)?

Comment: I would guess QT, http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely this is a [qt](http://qt-project.org/) [project file](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html).

Contents should be somewhat similar to this:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) 
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .

CONFIG += console
QT += opengl

# Input
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

If contents are significantly different (there are no "TEMPLATE", "SOURCES", etc), then it is something else.

To compile this project, you [need qt](http://qt-project.org/downloads) installed and configured on your system, so you can use [qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-running.html). You can also download [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/downloads), which might be easier for you to use.

You need to use qmake tool to generat visual studio solution file from this *.pro file.
Qt is a "broad" topic, so if you need to learn qt, I suggest to read through [its documentation](http://qt-project.org/resources/getting_started).

Answer (score -1):

if you can not compile thenoriginal project using vs2010 or 2012 you can create a new vc++ project in vs and copy the source code to it, (and link its dependencies...)
the special files(such as .pro file) will be correctly created.

now you can start your development